# Zip folder contents not being copied in

Tags: php, zip

I am currently trying to create a content uploading system and although there are error being made from the page when I check the appropriate folder for the contents it is empty

```
$chapterZip = new ZipArchive();

if ($chapterZip->open($_FILES['chapterUpload']['name'])) 
{ 
   for($i = 0; $i < $chapterZip->numFiles; $i++) 
   {   
     $pictureName = $chapterZip->getNameIndex($i);
     $fileOpened = $chapterZip->getStream($pictureName);
     if(!$fileOpened) exit("failed\n");
     while (!feof($fileOpened)) {
        $contents = fread($fileOpened, 8192);
        // do some stuff
        if(copy($contents,"Manga/".$_POST['mangaName']."/".$_POST['chapterName']."/".$pictureName.""))
        {
            if(chmod("Manga/".$_POST['mangaName']."/".$_POST['chapterName']."/".$pictureName."", 0664))
            {
              $errmsg0.= "File successfully copied<br/>";
            }
            else 
            {
              $errmsg0.= "Error: failed to chmod file<br/>";
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
           $errmsg0.= "Error: failed to copy file<br/>";
        } 
    }
    fclose($fileOpened);
  }
```

}

Any help with this problem would be much appreciated

Comment: The code is very hard to read. Can you explain in more detail what you are doing here?

Comment: You get an error or not?
Moreover, you mix reading bytes ($content) with file copy, I doubt it can work.
Omitting half of the code doesn't help either.

Comment: @Pekka
The code reads in a uploaded zip file from the site, opens the file and the loops through the contents copying it to the folders created earlier in the class.

@PhiLho
I'm not getting any errors and I have now included the entire method in the question, just thought it was a bit irrelevant to the question I was asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into it further and found a fairly simple method to extract file with on the PHP online manual

```
   $zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('test.zip');
if ($res === TRUE) {
    echo 'ok';
    $zip->extractTo('test');
    $zip->close();
} else {
    echo 'failed, code:' . $res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps you, but I wrote this script yesterday after some info I found searching for zipping recursively.

```
function zip($source, $destination)
    {
        if (file_exists($source) === true)
        {
            $zip = new ZipArchive();

            if ($zip->open($destination, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) === true)
            {
                $source = realpath($source);

                if (is_dir($source) === true)
                {
                    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

                    foreach ($files as $file)
                    {
                        $file = realpath($file);

                        if (is_dir($file) === true)
                        {
                            $zip->addEmptyDir(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file . '/'));
                        }

                        else if (is_file($file) === true)
                        {
                            $zip->addFromString(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file), file_get_contents($file));
                        }
                    }
                }

                else if (is_file($source) === true)
                {
                    $zip->addFromString(basename($source), file_get_contents($source));
                }
            }

            return $zip->close();
        }
     }
```

Found it on some website I can't remember where. Adapted it a slight bit.

Usage: zip('mydir/', 'myZipFile.zip');

Br,
Paul Peelen

Comment: `if (is_true($foo) === true) { $isIsTrueTrue = true; $isIsIsTrueTrueBoolean = is_boolean($isIsTrueTrue) === true; }`